# Libinput on touchscreen do not give me EVENT_DAWN only EVENT_UP

Tags: touchscreen, libinput, evdev

I try use libinput as default, and I dont get EVENT_DAWN, only  EVENT_UP , so I can not drag scrollbars or drag-and-drop some thing. Just pressing buttons only (without "dawn animation" )

I already try return evdev, it work well.
I can use both libs (one of them), but I like calibration matrix from libinput, it is size independent model

Touchscreen is eGalax Inc.

```
 xinput --test-xi2 --root
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc.                               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard System Control      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
EVENT type 22 (RawTouchBegin)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16831.74 (16831.74)
          1: 17791.73 (17791.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16831.74 (16831.74)
          1: 17759.73 (17759.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16831.74 (16831.74)
          1: 17631.73 (17631.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16831.74 (16831.74)
          1: 17695.73 (17695.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16895.74 (16895.74)
          1: 17759.73 (17759.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16895.74 (16895.74)
          1: 17695.73 (17695.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16895.74 (16895.74)
          1: 17631.73 (17631.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16927.74 (16927.74)
          1: 17631.73 (17631.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16927.74 (16927.74)
          1: 17567.73 (17567.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16991.74 (16991.74)
          1: 17567.73 (17567.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 17023.74 (17023.74)
          1: 17567.73 (17567.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16991.74 (16991.74)
          1: 17567.73 (17567.73)

EVENT type 23 (RawTouchUpdate)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16799.74 (16799.74)
          1: 17535.73 (17535.73)

EVENT type 24 (RawTouchEnd)
    device: 2 (11)
    detail: 103
    valuators:
          0: 16799.74 (0.00)
          1: 17535.73 (0.00)
```

UPD....
I use Ubuntu 20.04. My event missed not in touchscreen my event miss for front application. I can not hold scroll bars, I can not make drag-and-drop. I can make "click" but only when I remove finger from touchscreen, not when I touching it.

```
libinput debug-events --verbose
libinput version: 1.15.5
event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
event3  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event3  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
event7  - HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event8  - HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event6  - eGalax Inc.: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
event6  - eGalax Inc.: device is a touch device
event10 - HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event11 - HD-Audio Generic Line: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event12 - HD-Audio Generic Line Out: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event13 - HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event9  - HD-Audio Generic Front Mic: is tagged by udev as: Switch
event5  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
event5  - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
-event1   DEVICE_ADDED     Power Button                      seat0 default group1  cap:k
-event0   DEVICE_ADDED     Power Button                      seat0 default group2  cap:k
-event2   DEVICE_ADDED     Logitech USB Keyboard             seat0 default group3  cap:k
-event3   DEVICE_ADDED     Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control seat0 default group3  cap:k
-event4   DEVICE_ADDED     Logitech USB Keyboard System Control seat0 default group3  cap:k
-event7   DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3    seat0 default group4  cap:
-event8   DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7    seat0 default group4  cap:
-event6   DEVICE_ADDED     eGalax Inc.                       seat0 default group5  cap:t ntouches 1 calib
-event10  DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic         seat0 default group4  cap:
-event11  DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic Line             seat0 default group4  cap:
-event12  DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic Line Out         seat0 default group4  cap:
-event13  DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone  seat0 default group4  cap:
-event9   DEVICE_ADDED     HD-Audio Generic Front Mic        seat0 default group4  cap:
-event5   DEVICE_ADDED     Eee PC WMI hotkeys                seat0 default group6  cap:k
-event6   TOUCH_DOWN       +0.000s      -1 (0) 36.77/62.11 (753.00/1272.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.000s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.028s      -1 (0) 36.72/62.06 (752.00/1271.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.028s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.080s      -1 (0) 36.57/62.06 (749.00/1271.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.080s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.104s      -1 (0) 36.52/62.06 (748.00/1271.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.104s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.128s      -1 (0) 36.47/62.01 (747.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.128s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.179s      -1 (0) 36.47/62.06 (747.00/1271.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.179s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.203s      -1 (0) 36.47/62.01 (747.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.203s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.255s      -1 (0) 36.52/62.01 (748.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.255s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.283s      -1 (0) 36.52/61.96 (748.00/1269.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.283s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.382s      -1 (0) 36.47/62.01 (747.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.382s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.458s      -1 (0) 36.47/61.96 (747.00/1269.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.458s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.534s      -1 (0) 36.52/61.96 (748.00/1269.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.534s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.661s      -1 (0) 36.52/62.01 (748.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.661s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.713s      -1 (0) 36.57/62.01 (749.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.713s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.841s      -1 (0) 36.52/62.01 (748.00/1270.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.841s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.868s      -1 (0) 36.52/61.96 (748.00/1269.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.868s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.892s      -1 (0) 36.47/61.96 (747.00/1269.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.892s
 event6   TOUCH_MOTION     +0.968s      -1 (0) 36.52/62.06 (748.00/1271.00mm)
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.968s
 event6   TOUCH_UP         +0.992s
 event6   TOUCH_FRAME      +0.992s
```

and this....

```
 evemu-record
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      Power Button
/dev/input/event1:      Power Button
/dev/input/event2:      Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event3:      Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control
/dev/input/event4:      Logitech USB Keyboard System Control
/dev/input/event5:      Eee PC WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event6:      eGalax Inc.
/dev/input/event7:      HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event8:      HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event9:      HD-Audio Generic Front Mic
/dev/input/event10:     HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic
/dev/input/event11:     HD-Audio Generic Line
/dev/input/event12:     HD-Audio Generic Line Out
/dev/input/event13:     HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
Select the device event number [0-13]: 6
# EVEMU 1.3
# Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic
# DMI: dmi:bvnAmericanMegatrendsInc.:bvr2203:bd07/28/2020:svnSystemmanufacturer:pnSystemProductName:pvrSystemVersion:rvnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:rnPRIMEA320I-K:rvrRevX.0x:cvnDefaultstring:ct3:cvrDefaultstring:
# Input device name: "eGalax Inc."
# Input device ID: bus 0x03 vendor 0xeef product 0x01 version 0x100
# Supported events:
#   Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
#     Event code 0 (SYN_REPORT)
#     Event code 1 (SYN_CONFIG)
#     Event code 2 (SYN_MT_REPORT)
#     Event code 3 (SYN_DROPPED)
#     Event code 4 ((null))
#     Event code 5 ((null))
#     Event code 6 ((null))
#     Event code 7 ((null))
#     Event code 8 ((null))
#     Event code 9 ((null))
#     Event code 10 ((null))
#     Event code 11 ((null))
#     Event code 12 ((null))
#     Event code 13 ((null))
#     Event code 14 ((null))
#     Event code 15 (SYN_MAX)
#   Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
#     Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
#   Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
#     Event code 0 (ABS_X)
#       Value      748
#       Min          0
#       Max       2047
#       Fuzz         0
#       Flat         0
#       Resolution   0
#     Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
#       Value     1271
#       Min          0
#       Max       2047
#       Fuzz         0
#       Flat         0
#       Resolution   0
# Properties:
N: eGalax Inc.
I: 0003 0eef 0001 0100
P: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 03 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
A: 00 0 2047 0 0 0
A: 01 0 2047 0 0 0
################################
#      Waiting for events      #
################################
E: 0.000001 0001 014a 0001      # EV_KEY / BTN_TOUCH            1
E: 0.000001 0003 0000 1233      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1233
E: 0.000001 0003 0001 0930      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                930
E: 0.000001 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +0ms
E: 0.051775 0003 0000 1232      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1232
E: 0.051775 0003 0001 0931      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                931
E: 0.051775 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +51ms
E: 0.079657 0003 0000 1231      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1231
E: 0.079657 0003 0001 0932      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                932
E: 0.079657 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +28ms
E: 0.103556 0003 0000 1230      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1230
E: 0.103556 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.127452 0003 0000 1229      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1229
E: 0.127452 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.151359 0003 0001 0931      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                931
E: 0.151359 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.330595 0003 0001 0930      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                930
E: 0.330595 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +179ms
E: 0.458055 0003 0001 0929      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                929
E: 0.458055 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +128ms
E: 0.509836 0003 0001 0928      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                928
E: 0.509836 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +51ms
E: 0.537723 0003 0000 1230      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1230
E: 0.537723 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +28ms
E: 0.589501 0003 0001 0929      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                929
E: 0.589501 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +52ms
E: 0.665181 0003 0000 1229      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1229
E: 0.665181 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +76ms
E: 0.689079 0003 0001 0928      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                928
E: 0.689079 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.716961 0003 0001 0926      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                926
E: 0.716961 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +27ms
E: 0.740860 0003 0000 1230      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1230
E: 0.740860 0003 0001 0924      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                924
E: 0.740860 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.764767 0003 0001 0923      # EV_ABS / ABS_Y                923
E: 0.764767 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
E: 0.792643 0003 0000 1229      # EV_ABS / ABS_X                1229
E: 0.792643 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +28ms
E: 0.816547 0001 014a 0000      # EV_KEY / BTN_TOUCH            0
E: 0.816547 0000 0000 0000      # ------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +24ms
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, how do you know the issue is in missing event? Have you ran both `evemu-record` and `libinput debug-events --verbose`, and found out that the first one has the event, while the latter doesn't?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I add more report in post, I use Ubuntu 20.04. My event missed not in touchscreen my event miss for front application. I can not hold scroll bars, I can not make drag-and-drop. I can make "click" but only when I remove finger from touchscreen, not when I touching it